# Shall i use wrapper OR filter for addition of extra headers?

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I have a scenario.Due to some utility dependency A header is not being forwarded to my springboot application.So I tried to make a filter and created a request wrapper inside it.
What will be better solution only filter or only wrapper should be used?

Following is my code.Though it is working fine.I wanted to make it optimized.

```
@Component
public class AddVersionFilter implements Filter{
private static final Logger log = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(AddVersionFilter.class);
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
        ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(httpRequest) {           

        public String getHeader(String name) {
            String header = super.getHeader(name);
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Version") && header == null)
            {
                log.info("Setting Version");
                return "23";
            }
            else
            {
                log.info("other headers");
            return (header != null) ? header : super.getParameter(name); // Note: you can't use getParameterValues() here.
            }
        }

        public Enumeration<String>getHeaderNames() {
            List<String> names = Collections.list(super.getHeaderNames());
            names.addAll(Collections.list(super.getParameterNames()));
            names.add("Version");
            log.info(names.toString());
            return Collections.enumeration(names);

        }

    };

    chain.doFilter(wrapper, response);
    log.info(" schema version " +httpRequest.getHeader("Version"));

}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> So I tried to make a filter and created a request wrapper inside it. What will be better solution only filter or only wrapper should be used?

Wrappers and filters should be used in conjunction. You create a wrapper in your filter and pass the wrapper along in the call to chain.doFilter(...). Your code above is written that way and is good.

Couple of observations

1. Is it normal to return parameter names and values in calls to getHeader...()? I see that in two places in your code. You may want to check the default request object behaviour.
2. You may wish to override [getHeaders(name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html#getHeaders(java.lang.String)) from the HttpServletRequestObject.

Comment: the purpose was to sent the not null values back even if it is set as parameter.